# Unable to set up timedatectl to sync from a specific NTP server

Tags: networking, ntp

I am using my college's LAN and need my timedate to synchronize to the college's ntp server.

I tried editing the `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` appropriately (by change the value after `NTP=` but it keeps trying to synchronize from `ntp.ubuntu.com` (which won't work on lan)

Please advise

UPDATE: I have installed chrony and it seems to be working fine with this.

Comment: Please include the output of the following commands in your post: `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service` and `cat /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`.

Comment: Also did you restart the service after changing configuration?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Setting multiple NTP servers in /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048907/setting-multiple-ntp-servers-in-etc-systemd-timesyncd-conf)

Answer (score 0):

apt install ntp

Open /etc/ntp.conf
add

server yourlocalntpserver  iburst

systemctl restart ntp

date -R

Comment: Hi. This doesn't really answer the question, since the OP asked about configuring `timesyncd`. Installing another NTP app does not answer this.

Comment: Ack to @ArturMeinild and even if the request was for alternatives, I'd recommend the supported "chrony" instead of the demoted old "ntp"

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the NTP server setting in /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf.

```
NTP="your ntp server host name or address"
```

You can also set a fall back server

```
FallbackNTP="your fall back server host name or address"
```